# Error : attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import, importerror

I try to import the model.py file in populate_reusumeeditor.py But It keeps giving this error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` I have imported everything correctly even pycharm is not showing any error.

Here is model.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):

    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name


class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique = True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

here populate_reusumeeditor.py file

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Resumemake.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
from .resumeeditor.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['search','Social','Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']

def add_topics():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name = random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        top = add_topics()

        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic = top, url = fake_url, name = fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg, date = fake_date)[0]


if __name__== '__main__':
    print('Populating Script!')
    populate(20)
    print('Populating complete!')
```

Here is the flow of the project :

[image]

Comment: try delete first `.` in `from .resumeeditor.models `

Comment: I think the error is here: ```from .resumeeditor.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic```. The ```models.py``` and ```populate_reusumeeditor.py``` should be in the same directory

Comment: and where is `populate_reusumeeditor.py` located?

Comment: @newlife I firstly used 'resumeeditor.models' but it give me same error. and `populate_reusumeeditor.py`in resumemake directory

Comment: @Sujay Actually I am following one tutorial he has `populate_reusumeeditor.py` this file in resumemake folder. I tried `models.py` and `populate_reusumeeditor.py` it worked by using `from .models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic` this but in my database it's only showing it's not showing any data in my database